# Google Map Pin Points refresh from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, refresh

What will be the best way to `refresh` the `Pin Points` showing on Google Map by using `Javascript`? Like when i press a button and then the map will generate another different `pins`, by not loading the page again.

Answer (score 1):

The magic words you are looking for are "AJAX" (Asynchronous Javascript And Xml).  For a description see [the page "The AJAX Philosophy"](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm) from Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial or Google "AJAX"

Answer (score 0):

this question is pretty vague, "best" is hard to say without proper context. if points are being updated in the database after the page has been loaded you could use an ajax call attached to the button.